# Trailing comma after last line in object

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using Prettier in VS Code. I noticed that when using format on save, Prettier adds trailing commas on the last line of an object every time.

For example, let's say I had a JS object like this:

```
obj = {
 hello: 'hello',
 world: 'world'
}
```

Prettier turns it into this:

```
obj = {
 hello: 'hello',
 world: 'world',
}
```

> Notice the extra comma after `'world'`

Didn't find in the settings an option to fix this.

Comment: I have no idea about prettier but isn't this related? https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#trailing-commas

Comment: for me the behavior of prettier is opposite, it removes trailing comma.

Comment: You can try `"trailingComma": "all"` then or check if you are eslint also. That might be overriding some setting.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can update `.prettierrc.json` and set option [`trailingComma`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#trailing-commas) to `none` like:

```
{
  "trailingComma" : "none",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 65):

Trailing commas are a code-style convention that was introduced to avoid spurious differences in version controls (ie Git).

Imagine you have version controlled code and you have to change it. When you add a new line to your object without the trailing comma, you will have to change the original last line by adding a comma. In version control this then shows up as two changed lines. The code reviewer or a future dev have to check if you effectively changed the last line, or only added the comma.

Zuckerberg's answer shows you how to change it. However, it is better to change your style, than change *prettier*'s style.

Comment: Solution: apply the change to your entire codebase, commit that, and add the commit to `.git-blame-ignore-revs` so it doesn't show up in blame — see e.g. https://akrabat.com/ignoring-revisions-with-git-blame/

Comment: But the commit that adds a new item should not be ignored!

Comment: This is a great point, I highly feel why the last item should be in the change history if the change is unrelated. Highly recommend using `trailingComma: "es5"` ( the default is changed from `none` to `es5` from `v2.0.0` )

Comment: The same could apply to semicolons, and yet, they are on by default (there are situations, where this setting results in more lines changed in a diff). So I see good reasons to change some parts of Prettier's style.

Answer (score 19):

Trailing commas are a standard already because they result in a cleaner commit history. If you have to add a property down the road, git will show a single line changed instead of a new line AND the new comma on the previous line.

Answer (score 8):

To modify the setting in **VSCode**:

1. Go to FILE -> PREFERENCES -> SETTINGS. (VS Code Menus)
2. Settings window should open. Above (Top) there is a search. Type "Prettier"
3. You should see the available Prettier settings. You can modify them

Now change `trailingComma` to `none`

Answer (score 6):

Trailing commas are modern JS, but if you really don't like them [they can be disabled](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#trailing-commas).

Comment: could you add any source, any article about "trailing comma - modern js " ?

Comment: @YevheniiHerasymchuk It's not only JS. It's, for example, PHP too. Trailing commas avoid conflicts when two people add items to an array/object and then want to merge with git.
With a trailing comma, instead of a modified line + inserted line, you only get an inserted line which won't produce any conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone's wondering how to have VSCode's `prettier` extension behave like `pre-commit`'s `prettier` hook, this worked for me:

```
  "prettier.trailingComma": "all"
```

The above should be used in combination with `prettier` as  the`defaultFormatter` for the relevant files, as suggested by others.

If that alone is not enough and you're also using `EditorConfig` for other customizations, you may need to also add:

```
  "prettier.useEditorConfig": false
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Do you also know the explanation around it why vscode prettier extension behaves differently than prettier cli?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the configuration above was not enough:

```
{
  "trailingComma" : "none",
}
```

For this to work for me, in addition to this setting, I had to remove from ***setting.json***:

```
"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

And with the extension already installed `Prettier` next, enter the command
`ctrl + shift + P` in *vscode*

Click on `Configure...`

Choose `Prettier - Code formatter`

Now this:

```
const a = {
  a: 10,
  b: 15,
};
```

turns into this:

```
const a = {
  a: 10,
  b: 15
}
```