# Why prettier in VC do not put comma in the last item in list?

Tags: visual-studio, atom-editor, prettier

We all have prettier, the latest version. I have a Mac and Atom, other has Windows and VS. Why on Mac will have an ending `,` but VC guys will not have? I have on Atom a plugin and VS guys has a plugin as well to align code when saving.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trailing comma after last line in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370583/trailing-comma-after-last-line-in-object)

Comment: nope :( We have same version in VS and Atom, but prettier works differently

Comment: check the config, not just the version